# Composting camphor leaves?

Tags: plant-health, compost

I have been reading at various sites online that it is bad to compost camphor leaves because camphor is mildly allelopathic, specifically, inhibiting seed germination. I also see some other people stating that [camphor leaves were proven to not be allelopathic to other plants](https://www.houzz.com/discussions/3295481/composting-camphor-tree-leaves), citing an Australian study which I cannot find online.

My house is surrounded by several camphor trees and I had planned on using the leaves as a source of brown matter. How concerned should I be about this issue? I typically plant in the garden from purchased seedlings or seedlings that I germinated indoors so actual germination in the ground is not really an issue.